# SSRS Dataset column not refreshed when using stored procedure with multiple Select and parameters

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a report with a lot of datasets, and I want to make it easy for maintenance. I created a stored procedure that runs multiple select statements and accesses the data with parameters.

Sample stored procedure:

```
CREATE [dbo].[sp_test_report] 
    @inputReportPart varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@inputReportPart = '1' OR @inputReportPart = 'debug')
    BEGIN
        SELECT a, b, c 
        FROM table1
    END

    IF (@inputReportPart = '2' OR @inputReportPart = 'debug')
    BEGIN
        SELECT q, w, e 
        FROM table2
    END
END
```

But when I implement it to SSRS, the default column always use the first query even the parameter value is different.

Result:

- [Dataset view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLoiv.png)
- [Dataset1 property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieTG4.png)
- [Dataset2 property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxWlr.png)

I try to rebuild solution, `refresh field`, and delete `.rdl.data` but it doesn't work

Any solution other than add the column manually into dataset?

Comment: **Side note**: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: @marc_s well noted sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to make it easy for maintenance then i created stored procedure that store multiple select

That won't make anything easier. Use a different stored procedure for each dataset.

SSRS doesn't actually run your procedure to determine the dataset schema. So it will always discover the first resultset in the procedure, whether it uses FMTONLY or the newer [sp_describe_first_result_set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

If you really wanted to make this work you'd have to add [WITH RESULT SETS](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2356/overview-of-with-result-sets-feature-of-sql-server-2012/) to your Dataset query which enables the client to specify the resultset metadata.

Comment: i see, so its back to "add column but in query" right ? xD

my first thought is same like you say but its okay if the report have more than 10 dataset i mean that a lot of stored procedure/view only for 1 report ?

Comment: It does seem strange that you would want 10 different datasets for one report.

Comment: yeah what i can tell you that _it sums up all reports to 1_ that why im used a lot datasets,
anyway i tried what you said but had a problem that all my query must have the **same column number** and if not i must add a dummy column into it to match, i just think can i initialize the default value into `RESULT SETS`? so i dont need to add dummy column into query

Comment: Then why not write a stored procedure that outputs a single resultset?

Comment: because they have different needs that make its pretty difficulty to make it same, i tried to split it to several part/stored procedure but have the same problem with what i said before

Comment: and its back to what you said earlier `Use a different stored procedure for each dataset` xD, for now i think i will stick with 1 or split it to several stored procedure. 
btw back to my question you now how to add default value into `RESULT SETS`? i tried to google it but didnt find the answer/correct keyword